# Android Material Toolbar Notification Bar Not Showing

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar

I have a small problem. I don't understand toolbar problem. For example, I added toolbar in activity but not see notification panel background("primary_dark"). I tried everything, but it not solved.

[image]

> AboutActivity.java

```
package com.mikepenz.unsplash.activities;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.mikepenz.unsplash.R;

public class AboutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.about_activity_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("About");

    }
}
```

> activity_about.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/about_main_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

> Dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>

    <!-- fab sizes -->
    <dimen name="fab_small">40dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_normal">56dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_progress">72dp</dimen>

    <!-- fab specific margins -->
    <dimen name="fab_small_margin_right">24dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_small_margin_top">-20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_normal_margin_right">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_normal_margin_top">-28dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_progress_margin_right">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_progress_margin_top">-36dp</dimen>


    <dimen name="navigation_drawer_width">320dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="toolbar_elevation">4dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

> Styles.xml (v21)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="MaterialDrawerTheme.TranslucentStatus">
        <!-- improve animations -->
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.DetailActivity" parent="MaterialDrawerTheme.TranslucentStatus">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

> color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- item image -->
    <color name="image_without_palette">#1C1D23</color>
    <color name="text_without_palette">#ffeae1da</color>
    <color name="blue">#ff39495f</color>
    <color name="cyan">#2196F3</color>

    <!-- default theme colors -->
    <color name="primary">#313e52</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#263141</color>
    <color name="primary_light">#C5CAE9</color>
    <color name="background">#ECECEC</color>
    <color name="accent">#fff9f9f9</color>
    <color name="accent_button">#4f5a6b</color>
    <color name="primary_text">#ff212121</color>
    <color name="secondary_text">#727272</color>
    <color name="icons">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="divider">#B6B6B6</color>

    <!-- green fab button -->
    <color name="primary_green">#86d2a8</color>
    <color name="primary_dark_green">#ff4d7b61</color>
    <color name="accent_green">#ff72b38e</color>
    <color name="unfinished_progress">#AAFFFFFF</color>

    <!-- transparent -->
    <color name="transparent">#00FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="material_red">#E51C23</color>

    <!-- error view -->
    <color name="error_view_text">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="error_view_text_light">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="error_view_text_dark">#DEDEDE</color>



    <!-- Material DEFAULT drawer colors -->
    <color name="material_drawer_selected">#313e52</color>
    <color name="material_drawer_selected_text">#fafafa</color>
    <color name="material_drawer_dark_selected_text">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="material_drawer_dark_selected">#3e4754</color>
    <color name="material_drawer_dark_primary_icon">#fafafa</color>

    <!-- AboutLibraries DARK colors -->
    <color name="theme_window_background">#303030</color>
    <color name="about_libraries_card">#666666</color>
    <color name="about_libraries_title_openSource">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="about_libraries_text_openSource">#DEDEDE</color>
    <color name="about_libraries_dividerDark_openSource">#303030</color>
    <color name="about_libraries_dividerLight_openSource">#303030</color>
</resources>
```

> Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.mikepenz.unsplash">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:name="com.mikepenz.unsplash.CustomApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.mikepenz.unsplash.activities.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.mikepenz.unsplash.activities.DetailActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.DetailActivity">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.mikepenz.unsplash.activities.AboutActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/action_about">

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mikepenz.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/paths"/>
        </provider>

        <service android:name=".muzei.WallSplashSource"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:description="@string/muzei_description"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_source">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.muzei.api.MuzeiArtSource"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="color" android:value="#3F51B5"/>
        </service>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Style.xml file change the colorPrimaryDark color.

`<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>`

Also change the extends from `ActionBarActivity` to `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: I shared. Please look down.

Comment: Please include the color.xml file. Otherwise that,  it's not understandable.

Comment: Okey, I added. Please check it

Comment: Change the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your styles.xml with this

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseAppTheme"/>

    <style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and your styles.xml(v21) will look like this

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseAppTheme">
         <!-- improve animations -->
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In your manifest, define the theme for your application like this inside application tag

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

/*

   your activities

*/

</application>
```

The problem is you have specified the colorPrimaryDark for pre lollipop devices. you have to define the parent of your styles.xml(v21) as the one with colorPrimaryDark defined in your styles.xml.

Comment: can you share your manifest file? Also are you testing this in a lollipop device? do you have values-v21 folder in your res directory?

Comment: Yes, I try lollipop MainActivity Is normal but, AboutActivity Abnormal! I don't understand this file. Wait I'll add.

Comment: answer updated, the problem seems to be in the parent for your styles.xml(v21). Just try the two styles.xml I have provided for both lollipop and pre lollipop devices.